# Replacing values in a df based on a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

As a new Python user, I would like to ask you the following.

I have a CSV file includes categorical variables recorded in numbers and a different excel file with an explanation of them.

I would like to create a function to do that because there are several different variables like `Vehicle_Type`, `Age of Driver`, etc…

The code that I apply is like this and it works fine:

```
repl_dict = pd.read_excel("variable lookup.xls",
                          sheet_name="Vehicle Type", index_col="code").to_dict()["label"]
trainset["Vehicle_Type"] = trainset["Vehicle_Type"].map(repl_dict)
```

Is there any function for that?

Comment: _Is there any function for that?_ You mean a function different from `map()` ?

Comment: No, I mean a function that takes as an argument the name of the variable and replace every record in the df. Cause in my way I do it separately every time like


repl_dict = pd.read_excel("variable lookup.xls",
                          sheet_name="Sex of Driver", index_col="code").to_dict()["label"]
trainset["Sex_of_Driver"] = trainset["Sex_of_Driver"].map(repl_dict)

repl_dict = pd.read_excel("variable lookup.xls",
                          sheet_name="Age Band", index_col="code").to_dict()["label"]
trainset["Age_Band_of_Driver"] = trainset["Age_Band_of_Driver"].map(repl_dict)

Comment: Please add that, and any other relevant information (hint: [mcve]) to your post, it's practically impossible to read as a comment.

Comment: repl_dict = pd.read_excel("variable lookup.xls",
                          sheet_name="Vehicle Type", index_col="code").to_dict()["label"]
trainset["Vehicle_Type"] = trainset["Vehicle_Type"].map(repl_dict)

Comment: repl_dict = pd.read_excel("variable lookup.xls",
                          sheet_name="Was Vehicle Left Hand Drive", index_col="code").to_dict()["label"]
trainset["Was_Vehicle_Left_Hand_Drive?"] = trainset["Was_Vehicle_Left_Hand_Drive?"].map(repl_dict)

Comment: I can not make it more clear I don't know how to present it like code... I want instead of using every time this code by change the variable name that I want to read from the vlookup.file , to create a function that takes as arguments the name of the variable inlcuded in the look up file and replace the numerical record with the categorical one